# jQuery waypoints integration

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

Why is jQuery waypoints not working? 
I have read their documentation, tutorials everything, and it`s not working my full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="waypoint.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        var $counter = $('.counter');

        $counter.waypoint(function(){
          console.log('Waypoint!');
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .space{
        height:1200px;
        background-color:yellow;
      }
      .counter{
        height:200px;
        background-color:red; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="space"></div>
      <div class="counter"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `waypoint.js` in this example? You already have a jQuery script, Waypoints library script, and JS that uses Waypoints in the body.

Answer (score 0):

By default, waypoints fire when the top of the element hits the top of the viewport. In your stripped down example, I don't imagine there is enough content to make your window scrollable, and your `counter` element never touches the top of the window.